# Remove Spaces from SQL Results When Searching

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have an Access database that contains fields with spaces in them. I'm trying to allow a user to search for matches but the spaces in the results are returning no information.

```
var dtCustomers = new DataTable();
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Devices WHERE [Serial Number]='" + textBox1.Text + "'", conn);
adapter.Fill(dtCustomers);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtCustomers;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    row.Cells[0].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    row.Cells[28].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

The code above will return results from the database but if the database has a field that's entered as '1Z 4568 29z4h' then it won't be returned unless the user types it exactly like that. The results are displayed in a DataGridView. Is there a different query I should be using?

Comment: So remove spaces prior to the equality test, depending on your DB's syntax: `... WHERE REPLACE([Serial Number], " ", "")='...`  You should also use a parameterized query as currently you have an SQL Injection vulnerability. (Remove any spaces from that parameters value as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL's [`replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) function to replace all spaces in `[Serial Number]` column to nothing, and use `textBox1.Text.Replace(' ','')` to make sure the user's input doesn't have spaces too:

```
var dtCustomers = new DataTable();
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM Devices WHERE replace([Serial Number], " ", "")='" + textBox1.Text.Relpace(' ','') + "'", conn);
adapter.Fill(dtCustomers);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtCustomers;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    row.Cells[0].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    row.Cells[28].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Then you need to replace the empty char in the user input as well: `textBox1.Text.Replace(...)` in order to match user input in a relaxed way

Comment: I get an error that says, "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Undefined function 'REPLACE' in expression.'"

The query also doesn't like the use of " ", "" and says that OleDbDataAdapter doesn't support 4 overloads. Replacing the quotation marks with apostrophe's removes that error.

Comment: I get an error when I try to run the search that says, "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression." The content I'm searching for in the Access database is text even though it appears to be numbers. Would that be causing this issue?